# How can I fix a missing return statement in Bubblesort?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am completely new to Java and haven't the slightest clue about it. I've been 'taught' it for a few months now but I still have trouble understanding it.

Here's my code giving the error:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bubblesort {

  private int x,y,n;
  private int arr[];

  public Component createComponents() {
    int temp; 
    for (int x = 0; x < n - 1; x++) { 
      for (int y = x + 1; y < n; y++) { 
        if (arr[x] > arr[y]) { 
          temp = arr[y]; 
          arr[y] = arr[x]; 
          arr[x] = temp; 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I've tried a few random return statements, but like I said.. I really don't know what I'm doing, so what **do** I have to to do?

Comment: Honestly if you have been taking lessons for a few *month* and still have problems with *these* basics, consider changing course.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on what the question is but here is a [good java bubble sort example](http://www.java-examples.com/java-bubble-sort-example) you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return something, you should return an int array instead of a Component, like this:

```
public int[] createComponents() {
    int temp; 
    for (int x = 0; x < n - 1; x++) { 
      for (int y = x + 1; y < n; y++) { 
        if (arr[x] > arr[y]) { 
          temp = arr[y]; 
          arr[y] = arr[x]; 
          arr[x] = temp; 
        } 
      } 
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

Comment: if you want to return array you should have a reference to it.
     public int[] createComponents(int[] arr){...}

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Main to get things going.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html for the classic "Hello World."

In it, you'll also see how to write to the console (`System.out.println`). The Main is also where you could put numbers in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is type Component at the end of that you'd need to return a component

```
Component x = foo;
```

Then at the bottom of your function

```
return foo;
```

Though in this case I'd recommend a type `int[]` or type `void` where you would not have to have a return statement. Personally I recommend the latter as that's how I typically do it and it would line up with your code better since your array is public thus not needing to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. createComponents() should return an int[] not a Component.
2. arr is never initialized. Create a constructor in your class that
   initializes the array with values.
3. Create a main() method in your class, so you can instantiate a Bubblesort object and call
   createComponents()

Comment: createComponents() should return Component[]

Comment: I'm not even sure why Component is in the discussion. OP didn't make that clear. But this appears to be a sorting program, and that method is manipulating an int[] named arr. So I'm assuming it should return an int[]. That method does nothing with a Component object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that before implementing an algorithm in any language, you should first write a pseudo code and then go on implementation.Implementation of Algorithm like bubble sort like this certainly not the best way to learn and implement Java Technology.I would recommend going through some Java Tutorials first , get your hands on with *" Hello World "* and understand the basics.Best Luck!!